# Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is pointed...$\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to its category of pointed objects $\mathcal{C}^{\ast/}$ ?

Tags: category-theory

**Definition 1.** A category is called **pointed** if it has a zero object, i.e. if it has an initial object and a terminal object and they are isomorphic.

**Definition 2.** For $\mathcal{C}$ a category with terminal object $\ast$, **the coslice category** $\mathcal{C}^{\ast/}$ is the corresponding **category of pointed objects**: its

- objects... are morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$ of the form $\ast \overset{x}{\to} X$ (hence an object $X$ equipped with a choice of point; i.e. pointed object).
- morphisms... in $\mathcal{C}$ which preserve the chosen points.

Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is pointed.

- $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to its category of pointed objects $\mathcal{C}^{\ast/}$ ?
- What is the relationship between these two definitions?

Comment: 1. Yes, this follows immediately from the definition, as $\bullet$ is initial. 2. Every coslice category is pointed, with $\bullet$ as the zero object.

Comment: Is it to say that in any pointy category, does the definition of smash product (tensorail product) make sense?...This is wonderful!

Comment: I don't understand the connection between that question and anything that has been previously said, but see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/smash+product#ForGeneralPointedObjects.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan... thanks!.... Excuse me ... I'm "thinking out loud"...
I barely realize that in any category with zero object you can define a tensor product ...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. The construction I linked to takes as input an existing monoidal structure.

Comment: I find a relationship what appears here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pointed+object  Definition 4.6

Comment: In that construction the existing monoidal structure is the cartesian product.

Comment: I understand ... There is a construction by means of colimits of the smash product but it does not necessarily reproduce the role of the tensor product.